# Chrome Packaged App: Filesystem API - Creating multiple files and directories after choosing a location

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm currently creating a Chrome Packaged App and was wondering if it's possible to create multiple files and directories after a user chooses a directory to create them in. For example, the user selects "My Documents", this much I can do, and I'm able to write a file to the directory selected, but only if prompted. My question is, is is possible to create a directories or multiple files without asking the user? I'm playing around with a possible "Game Engine", and need it to create a few directories/files when you click new project.

Again, I'm able to select the directory already, I just need to know how to write directories/files to it without prompting the user.

I'm currently using the following permissions:

1) storage

2) {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]}

3) fileSystemProvider

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this more tomorrow, bookmarked.